# SVN Novice : Setting up new repo

Tags: svn

I am a novice when it comes to using SVN on a command line. Previously I had done everything through a client.

I have created a new repository on my server like this:

```
%svnadmin create myrepo
```

However when I examine it, the trunk branches and tags are missing.

```
%cd myrepo/
%ll
total 14
229 Jul 28 10:22 README.txt
512 Jul 28 10:22 conf
512 Jul 28 10:22 dav
512 Jul 28 10:22 db
  2 Jul 28 10:22 format
512 Jul 28 10:22 hooks
512 Jul 28 10:22 locks
```

Do I need to create these manually? If so, do I just 'mkdir trunk', I thought you are not supposed to do anything to the files inside of the repo manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to create those folders manually.

You can either create the folders, then use

`svn import`

to import an existing structure, or, you can create the folders, then use

`svn add foldername`

for each folder you create.

I'd take a read of the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html) to get a better understanding of svn.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the SVN book.

Answer (score 2):

"svnadmin create" creates file structure for the subversion backend. You need to manipulate it through the svn command. A new SVN repository has no files in it and you need to add the trunk, branches and tags directories yourself. Try:

```
# svn mkdir file://./myrepo/trunk -m "Add trunk directory"
# svn list file://./myrepo
```

You should now see your directory.

A better method would be to checkout your repository and add the directories there:

```
# svn checkout file://./myrepo/ myrepo-checkout
# cd myrepo-checkout
# mkdir tags branches trunk
# svn add tags branches trunk
# svn commit -m "add initial directories"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: first create the default tree (branches, tags and trunk) in a temporal directory:

```
mkdir branches
mkdir tags
mkdir trunk
svn import myrepotemp file:///myrepo/ -m "Initial layout"
```

Anyway, you will not see this layout in the repo directory.